# c++ vector push back error

Tags: c++, vector, fstream, push-back

Im getting an error every time I try to debug this with Visual C++ 2008

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void load(const char* filename) {
    vector <string*> vec;
    ifstream in(filename);
    char buffer[256];
    while(!in.eof()) {
        in.getline(buffer, 256);
        vec.push_back(new std::string(buffer));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

get this error

```
Compiling...
main.cpp
Linking...
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Vector_const_iterator,class std::allocator > *,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > *> >::_Vector_const_iterator,class std::allocator > *,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > *> >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > * *,class std::_Container_base_secure const *)" (??0?$_Vector_const_iterator@PAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@PAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@QAE@PAPAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@PBV_Container_base_secure@1@@Z)
E:\blabla\Debug\test2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you're mixing debug & release settings. The code should work.

Comment: On a side note, I would suggest using vector<char> as a buffer, as opposed to char[]. Btw, the code compiles for me, must be your project settings.

Comment: Can you try it on VC++ 2010 or 2012 because it works on them.

Comment: Code runs fine in my PC, using VS2012 Express.

Comment: No need to use `new std::string(buffer)`. You are already `using namespace std;`. Instead, use `new string(buffer)`

Comment: Have you turned on MultiThreaded debug DLL in Project ->  [project name] properties -> C/C++ --> Code Generation --> Runtime Library by any chance?

Comment: @ecbrodie or better yet git rid of `using namespace std;` and add `std::` everywhere else.

Comment: Use `vector<string>`; there's no need for a container of pointers here. That won't fix the problem, but it will save you many headaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though you're building a debug version of your project but you're linking against the non-debug version of the C-Runtime DLL.  You can check this in:

```
[Project] -> Properties -> C/C++ --> Code Generation --> Runtime Library
```

The runtime library should be listed as: "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" for a debug build.

You should actually find that the project builds just fine as "Release" since `CrtDbgReportW` is not called by `std::vector` in release builds and hence doesn't need to find that symbol at link time.

Comment: It did work fine with release! Thanks!
Can you tell me the different og link me some stuff with the different between debug and release? Becuase I've never run with release before.

Comment: @PeterBechP I don't have a link to hand, but the main difference is that debug binaries are not optimized meaning that they run more slowly but are easier to run through in the debugger.  The compiler performs a whole array of optimizations on release binaries that make them tricky to debug (for example preventing you from setting break points in certain places or see certain values)

Comment: Okay. That made sense for me. But can i just use release for my projects then? :-)

Comment: @PeterBechP I strongly suggest that you do use a release build once you've finished development.  Debug is however handy while you're making fixes, I regularly switch between the two.